# Html not send post data to php

Tags: php, html

I don't know why my html form is not sending data. I have 3 file called `default.php`, `prosesbacasoal.php` and `bacasoal.php`. Because the default.php is too long I just write the html form I get from inspect element

```
<form method="post" action="prosesbacasoal.php"><div class="head-main-   recenttest-result">
<input type="hidden" name="nomor" value="2">
<button class="head-main-recenttest-result-wait" style="text-decoration:none;" type="submit" name="submit">2.Soal Kedua</button> </div></form>
```

prosesbacasoal.php

```
 <?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if(isset($_POST['nomor'])) {
$_SESSION['submitsoal'] = true;
$_SESSION['nomorsoal'] = $_POST['nomor'];
header("Location:bacasoal.php");
exit;
} else {
header("Location:bacasoal.php");
exit;
}
} else {
header("Location:bacasoal.php");
exit;
}
?>
```

Also the bacasoal.php is too long so I just write the part of it:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['submitsoal'])) {
if(isset($_SESSION['nomorsoal'])) {
$nomorsoal = $_SESSION['nomorsoal'];
$queryjudulnya = "SELECT nomorsoal,judul,soal FROM soal WHERE   nomorsoal='".$nomorsoal."'";
$runqueryjudulnya = mysqli_query($konek,$queryjudulnya);
$countqueryjudulnya = mysqli_num_rows($runqueryjudulnya);
if($countqueryjudulnya != 0) {
$assocqueryjudulnya = mysqli_fetch_assoc($runqueryjudulnya);
$juduldatabase = mysqli_real_escape_string($assocqueryjudulnya['judul']);
$soaldatabase = mysqli_real_escape_string($assocqueryjudulnya['soal']);
$nomorsoaldatabase =      mysqli_real_escape_string($assocqueryjudulnya['nomorsoal']);
} else {}
} else {}
} else {}
?>

<?php 
if(isset($juduldatabase) && isset($nomorsoaldatabase)) {
echo "<div class=\"head-main-recent\"> ".$nomorsoaldatabase.$juduldatabase."  </div>";
} else {
echo "<div class=\"head-main-recent\">Judul soal tidak ditemukan!</div>";
}
?>
```

`bacasoal.php` keep echo the fail statement `"Judul soal tidak ditemukan!"`

Does anyone know why? (live demo : http://english-lesson.16mb.com/)

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string` requires the connection object as the 1st parameter if using it in procedural style as you do here - but why use that AFTER querying the db?

Comment: Anant that's unsafe tho

Comment: i put connect method to mysqli real escape string but still no change

Comment: @FajarMerahDiwangkaraa nope, since you are not going to use those values in query again  (as shown) so that is not at all required

Comment: After `<?php
session_start();` add `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` and check any error is coming or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below so that if error is there then it will display or any how at-least some useful information  will display:-

*default.php:-*

```
<form method="post" action="prosesbacasoal.php">
<div class="head-main-recenttest-result">
    <input type="hidden" name="nomor" value="2">
    <button class="head-main-recenttest-result-wait" style="text-decoration:none;" type="submit" name="submit">2.Soal Kedua</button> 
</div>
</form>
```

*prosesbacasoal.php:-*

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
if(isset($_POST['nomor'])) {
$_SESSION['submitsoal'] = 'true';
$_SESSION['nomorsoal'] = $_POST['nomor'];
header("location:bacasoal.php");
exit;
} else {
header("location:default.php");
exit;
}
?>
```

*bacasoal.php:-*

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
$juduldatabase = '';
$soaldatabase = '';
$nomorsoaldatabase = '';
if(isset($_SESSION['submitsoal']) && isset($_SESSION['nomorsoal'])) {
    $nomorsoal = $_SESSION['nomorsoal'];
    $queryjudulnya = "SELECT nomorsoal,judul,soal FROM soal WHERE   nomorsoal='".$nomorsoal."'";
    echo $queryjudulnya;
    $runqueryjudulnya = mysqli_query($konek,$queryjudulnya);
    if($runqueryjudulnya){
        $countqueryjudulnya = mysqli_num_rows($runqueryjudulnya);
        if($countqueryjudulnya > 0) {
            while($assocqueryjudulnya = mysqli_fetch_assoc($runqueryjudulnya)){
                $juduldatabase = $assocqueryjudulnya['judul'];
                $soaldatabase = $assocqueryjudulnya['soal'];
                $nomorsoaldatabase =  $assocqueryjudulnya['nomorsoal'];
            }
        } else {
            echo "No matching record found";
        }
    }else{
        echo "Query execution failed because of:-".mysqli_error($konek);
    }
}else {
    echo "Session variables are not set";
}
?>
<?php 
if(isset($juduldatabase) && isset($nomorsoaldatabase)) {
echo "<div class="head-main-recent"> ".$nomorsoaldatabase.$juduldatabase."</div>";
} else {
echo "<div class="head-main-recent">Judul soal tidak ditemukan!</div>";
}
?>
```

Note:- if still no error and no records,then echo query and run that query manually in db and check any record are coming or not?

Comment: sorry for late answer i having a lunch , ok i will try it first

Comment: go to english-lesson.16mb.com and click one button below " Tunggu soal berikutnya! " you will see the result tho

Comment: found the error , after i use inspect element to find hidden echo , i saw this result : Session variable are not set , but i already set it in prosesbacasoal.php , okay this is going very far i guess

Answer (score 1):

In 3rd line of your HTML code I can see `</div>` before form tag ending. I cant see dive start tag after form tag

```
<button class="head-main-recenttest-result-wait" style="text-decoration:none;" type="submit" name="submit">2.Soal Kedua</button> </div></form>
```

Replace by

```
<button class="head-main-recenttest-result-wait" style="text-decoration:none;" type="submit" name="submit">2.Soal Kedua</button></form>
```

Comment: @FajarMerahDiwangkaraa  check once again my edited answer and let me know worked or not?

Answer (score 0):

it was php session problem , fixed it after i session_destroy(); it using logout.php